# Unable to refresh or reset my computer

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot

Sony Vaio E Series running Windows 8:

1. The computer is unable to refresh or reset itself.
2. Automatic repair doesn't work.
3. Assist button also not working.

If anyone can help me, please instruct me correct steps to resolve this issue. I will be thankful.

Comment: Reinstall Windows from your backup.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a disk image or installation disk, [download the Windows 8.1 ISO image from MS](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows8) and reinstall it. Some of your files *might* survive installation, but it's best to copy them to another disk or USB flash drive first.